# Can't add more then one user to the table. Identity Insert is set to off

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Here is the error i get when i click on submit on my form to add a new user. I tried to set IDENTITY to ON trough query on User Table and it didn't help. I don't know how can i set it on and off when i'm not inserting data myself. Any suggestions?

[image]
Here is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(User U)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (SomeEntities dc = new SomeEntities ())
            {
                //you should check duplicate registration here 
                dc.Users.Add(U);
                dc.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                U = null;
                ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Registration Done";
            }
        }
        return View(U);
    }
```

Here Is my User Model:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
        this.PostFeedbacks = new HashSet<PostFeedback>();
        this.ProjectUsers = new HashSet<ProjectUser>();
        this.UserWithdraws = new HashSet<UserWithdraw>();
    }

    public decimal user_id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide username", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string user_name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide Password", AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Password must be 8 char long.")]
    public string user_pass { get; set; }

    [Compare("user_pass", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password dose not match.")]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    public string confirm_user_pass { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide full name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string full_name { get; set; }
```

Comment: How did you try to set identity insert to on? Did you do:                           SET IDENTITY_INSERT User ON?

Comment: Why even have an identity if you are just going to provide your own values anyway? This seems like a recipe for collisions to me.

Comment: Yes i did ET IDENTITY_INSERT Users ON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to set the identity explicitly, or are you ok with letting the db set the identity on insert? If the latter, just leave IDENTITY_INSERT set to OFF and ensure the identity column is set to its default.

In addition, ensure that you tag your identity column as such. ex.

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID {get; protected set;}
```

Comment: Which property is your key? `cj_user_id`? It seems very odd to have a decimal as the primary key on a table. Are you missing a property in the code you pasted above?
Also, is the primary key in the User coming into the controller 0? If it's not the default value for its type, it assumes you are trying an explicit identity insert, so place a debug breakpoint before your save and double-check that.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this before when using LINQ when i've not set the primary key identity to be "Is Identity" in the table design.

Comment: I have it set to IsIdentity True

Comment: Ok. So what you were trying to do was insert the user with the primary id of 0 each time. If you set identity_insert to off now. Has this fixed your issue?